# code for LLL algorithm in pari/gp

Tags: c++, c, cryptography, pari-gp, mathematical-lattices

I know that in PARI/GP the function `qflll` performs LLL algorithm on a set of bases. However, is it possible for me to look at the code for `qflll` in the PARI/GP library? Or does anyone know how does the LLL algorithm work in the PARI/GP library?

Comment: Yes, it is possible for you. [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) is free software under the GNU General Public License, so you can just [download the source code](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/download.html) and see for yourself.

Comment: (14:39) gp > ? idealred
idealred(nf,I,{v=0}): LLL reduction of the ideal I in the number field nf along direction v, in HNF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PARI/GP source can be downloaded using git

```
git clone http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/git/pari.git
```

or you can examine the source online. Here's a link to the LLL section:

http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=pari.git;a=blob;f=src/basemath/lll.c#l504